# jQuery AJAX POST to mysql table for dynamic table data- Am I doing this in anything like the right way?

Tags: php, mysql, html, jquery

I have a table which I can dynamically add and delete any number of rows to. Once the data is all entered by the user I am using the jQuery AJAX functionality to POST it to a mysql database so there is no page redirect or refresh.

The only way I could think of getting it to work was using this for loop in my jQuery, effectively posting each row to the database separately. How dumb is this? Should I be getting all the table data and posting it once? There could be any number of rows varying on user and the user could add and delete rows as much as he wants before submitting.

The strange i variable counting is due to there being two th rows at the top of the table. I couldn't work out a smart way of doing this.

I was a bit paranoid about the data always being associated with the correct row.

Thankyou for your time.

```
jQuery(function() {  
  jQuery(".button1").click(function() {  
    // process form here
    var rowCount = jQuery('#dataTable tr').length;

    for (var i = 2; i < rowCount; i++){
    // the four elements of each row I am storing to the mysql
    var txtRow1 = jQuery('#txtRow' + (i-1)).val();
    var tickerRow1 = jQuery('#tickerRow' + (i-1)).val();
    var quantRow1 = jQuery('#quantRow' + (i-1)).val();
    var valueRow1 = jQuery('#valueRow' + (i-1)).val();

    var dataString = 'txtRow1='+ txtRow1 + '&tickerRow1=' + tickerRow1 + '&quantRow1=' + quantRow1 + '&valueRow1=' + valueRow1;  
    //alert (dataString);return false;  
    jQuery.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "http://rccl.co.uk/form_action1.php",  
    data: dataString
    });  
    };
return false;  
});  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks very clearly to me as if you have a well-established index of the row in question, using your variable **i**.  Most form handlers server-side will unpack repeated keys of the form into a list, for stuff like many checkboxes with the same name.  You could exploit that here.

```
datastring = '';
for(var i=2; i<rowCount; i++) {
    var txtRow1 = jQuery('#txtRow' + (i-1)).val();
    var tickerRow1 = jQuery('#tickerRow' + (i-1)).val();
    var quantRow1 = jQuery('#quantRow' + (i-1)).val();
    var valueRow1 = jQuery('#valueRow' + (i-1)).val();
    dataString = datastring + 'index[]=' + (i-1) + 'txtRow1[]='+ txtRow1 + '&tickerRow1[]=' + tickerRow1 + '&quantRow1[]=' + quantRow1 + '&valueRow1[]=' + valueRow1;
}
```

Then make the ajax call with the whole string.

On the server-side, you should get arrays for each of these, the first of each of which corresponds to the first row, the second of each of which corresponds to the second row, and so on.

It's been a long time since I used PHP, but I believe the `[]` symbols for each key item are necessary to clue PHP's `$_POST` that it should convert the various keys' contents into arrays.

Comment: Going to take me quite some time to digest what you have written. Thankyou very much for your quick response.

Comment: I can use the code you wrote, but I don't know what to do with it. I don't know how the code knows to associate the right data with the first array to the nth array. It seems like I need an array of arrays instead of the final dataString variable, or the dataString variable should be an array of arrays, for the 1 through n rows of data.

Comment: $_POST["index"], $_POST["txtRow1"], $_POST["ticketRow1"] will all be arrays, and the zero'th item will all be for row 1, the 1st item will all be row 2, the 2nd item will all be row 3, etc.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your reply. The linked post is the way I have decided to go (even though it still isn't working), just because I can understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

I would try posting it all at once.

Reasons

1. fewer calls, less chance of your message getting lost in transit (your server rejecting requests because of flood)
2. you don't have to worry about requests responding out of order (maybe not an issue, but having an ass load of jumbled responses could potentially be an issue)
3. it will be faster for large numbers of rows getting saved at once

Comment: All very good points. I didn't think of there being a partial post of just some of the rows or other things you point out. Thank you very much.