# AJAX POST of multidimensional array- writing to MYSQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

With thanks to Elf Sternberg (I couldn't get your solution working, sorry), I think I am heading in the right direction, but I am having trouble writing the php to the mysql database.

The original post: [jQuery AJAX POST to mysql table for dynamic table data- Am I doing this in anything like the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287975/jquery-ajax-post-to-mysql-table-for-dynamic-table-data-am-i-doing-this-in-anythi)

Firstly, the dynamic table form on my webpage has multiple user input data, and I am using this jQuery function and the AJAX call to send to a php file. Am I correctly creating the multidimensional array here? Firebug shows dataString to have all the data I want, but the POST parameters and source just say dataString. Also the alert function shows the data is all there:

EDIT: With thanks to Jancha and Andrew, I have changed the data source for the AJAX post. The database is being written to now, but only BLANK data gets written, for as many entries as were in the table. The firebug console is showing all the data as it should look in the post. I just don't know how to structure the php loop now.

```
  jQuery(function() {  
  jQuery(".button1").click(function() {  
    // process form here
    var rowCount = jQuery('#dataTable tr').length;

    var dataString = [];
    dataString.length = rowCount - 2;
    for(var i=2; i<rowCount; i++) {
    var txtRow1 = jQuery('#txtRow' + (i-1)).val();
    var tickerRow1 = jQuery('#tickerRow' + (i-1)).val();
    var quantRow1 = jQuery('#quantRow' + (i-1)).val();
    var valueRow1 = jQuery('#valueRow' + (i-1)).val();
    // previous code: dataString[i-2] = 'txtRow1='+ txtRow1 + '&tickerRow1=' + tickerRow1 + '&quantRow1=' + quantRow1 + '&valueRow1=' + valueRow1; 
    // new code:
    dataString[i-2] = [txtRow1, tickerRow1, quantRow1, valueRow1];
    }       
    //alert (dataString);return false;  

    jQuery.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "form_action2.php",  
    data: { 'data': dataString }
    });  
return false;  
});  
});
```

If this is sending the data okay then I am thinking that the php function needs to look something like this:

Could I have help with the php function please. Thankyou for your time.

```
$data = $_POST['data'];


foreach ($data as $key => $value){

$txtRow1 = $data['txtRow1'];
$tickerRow1 = $data['tickerRow1'];
$quantRow1 = $data['quantRow1'];
$valueRow1 = $data['valueRow1'];

$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO stock_port (name, ticker, quantity, value) VALUES ('$txtRow1', '$tickerRow1', '$quantRow1', '$valueRow1')"; 

mysql_query($sqlinsert, $conn);
}
```

FINAL EDIT: Ok so this works to enter the data into the database:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];

foreach ($data as $value){
$txtRow1 = $value[0];
$tickerRow1 = $value[1];
$quantRow1 = $value[2];
$valueRow1 = $value[3];

$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO stock_port (name, ticker, quantity, value) VALUES ('$txtRow1', '$tickerRow1', '$quantRow1', '$valueRow1')"; 

mysql_query($sqlinsert, $conn);
}
```

It seems using data: {'data':dataString} in the AJAX jQuery call means I lost all the variable names of the data sent in the array to POST. Even though this is working, it doesn't feel like the way it should have been done. I have seen others use array structure in their id or names for input on forms, and that seems like it should have been the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

change `data: "dataString"` to `data: dataString` or else you are not passing variable but a 'string'.

Comment: Are you sure about this. I actually changed it from data: dataString, to data: "dataString" on the advice of stack overflow question I searched. If I make the change you suggested I get undefined as the POST information in the firebug console.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ data: "Object, String
Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string." so, I'm more than sure it should be without quotes if you want to pass actual array rather than string "dataString". put console.log(dataString); right before the jQuery.ajax and see in console what it is. if it's still undefined, problem is above with the cycle that generates it.

Comment: When I inspect dataString it has all the data in it that I think it should have, so I don't think the problem is creating the variable dataString.

Comment: I have changed the code to create the array, it now looks a lot more like it should in firebug when queried. However the source of the post in the console still just says 'dataString' when using " quotes and undefined when I don't use ".

Comment: I agree with jancha. If you want $_POST['whatever'] to be set you need to pass your dataString variable as an object. Wrapping it in double quotes does not pass the values of dataString (JavaScript does not work that way). You should do this: data: { 'whatever': dataString }

Comment: Thankyou both. Using data: {'data':dataString} gives me an actual correct output from firebugs console. However, it is only writing blank data to the database with the php code I have.

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem with your foreach statement try this

```
$data = $_POST['datastring'];
foreach($data as $key => $value){
  $txtRow1 = $data['txtRow1'];
}
```

It is not tested still you try once

Comment: I tried this but it also didn't write to the database. It looks much more right that what I had. It might be that the data is not getting to the php file in the right format. That is what jancha thinks. Although, using your suggestion and his suggestion together also, doesn't write to the database.